# XPath results to empty string

Tags: java, xml, xpath

Following is my XML file

```
<xyzevent xmlns="http://www.xyz.com/common/xyzevent/v1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org2001XMLSchema-instance">
<header>
 ----
</header>
<subscription xmlns="http://www.xyz.com/common/xyzevent/source/v1">
  <sender></sender>
  <receiver>
    <clientsubscription>
        <servicemap>nanna</servicemap>
    </clientsubscription>
  </receiver>
</subscription> 
</xyzevent>
```

When I budila org.w3c.dom.Document from this XML and applying XPathExperssion with expression

```
/xyzevent/subscription/receiver/clientsubscription/servicemap/text()
```

results empty string. What can be the issue with the expression?

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because your XML document uses a namespace. XPath is really annoying with namespaces. To confirm this, strip the two `xmlns=http://.../v1` from the document and run your XPath expression agains the unnamespaced, unverifiable XML file. It'll match.

What's happening is that your XPath expression tries to select `/xyzevent`, when your document contains `{http://.../v1}:xyzevent`, which is not the same thing.

There are various ways around this problem. The proper way is to set up a `NamespaceContext` so you can use the `prefix:localName` notation in your XPath expression and have the prefixes be resolved to the correct URI. There's a short blurb about this in the [xerces docs](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/xpath_apis.html#namespacecontext) and some more  [elsewhere on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914013/namespacecontext-and-using-namespaces-with-xpath). There's an extensive description at [ibm.com](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-nmspccontext/).

Your `NamespaceContext` will contain two (or more) mappings:

```
{
    event => http://www.xyz.com/common/xyzevent/v1
    source => http://www.xyz.com/common/xyzevent/source/v1
}
```

Your XPath expression can then become `/event:xyzevent/source:subscription/source:receiver/.../text()`.

As a *nasty* workaround, you can rewrite your xpath expression to select using the `local-name()` function:

```
/*[local-name()='xyzevent']/*[local-name()='subscription'/ ...
```

In this case, the expression matches any element whose local name is `xyzevent`, regardless of namespace URI.

Comment: After removing xmlns=http://.../v1 this from both the places I am able to get the value. But can you explain me how to build NamespaceContext to get when we have both the namespace values in document...

Comment: @Pokuri Register two separate prefixes in your `NamespaceContext`, e.g. `event` and `source` with the proper URI's for each. Your XPath expression will become `/event:xyzevent/source:subscription/source:receiver/...`

Comment: But NamespaceContext expects one namespaceURI and one or more prefixes. Then how can I pass two NamespaceContext to XPath.setNamespaceContext(namespaceContext); method

Comment: The example on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914013/namespacecontext-and-using-namespaces-with-xpath/920239#920239 covers this.

Answer (score 2):

Your XML has default namespace: `xmlns="http://www.xyz.com/common/xyzevent/v1"`, therefore you need to define it in your XML/XPath engine.

Or use this XPath:

```
/*[local-name() = 'xyzevent']
    /*[local-name() = 'subscription']
        /*[local-name() = 'receiver']
            /*[local-name() = 'clientsubscription']
                /*[local-name() = 'servicemap']
                    /text()
```

Answer (score 1):

`xyzevent` is your root element, so you just need to use `"/subscription/receiver/clientsubscription/servicemap/text()"`.

Answer (score 1):

I evaluated your expression in the following link:

http://www.whitebeam.org/library/guide/TechNotes/xpathtestbed.rhtm

And it seems, it selects "nanna".