# Extracting a term from SOAP header

Tags: java, xml, soap, xpath, soapheader

I would like to extract an element called ServiceGroupID from the SOAP header, which specifies the session of the transaction. I would need this so that I could direct the request to the same server using SOAP session. My XML is as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" standalone="no"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<wsa:ReplyTo>
<wsa:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/none</wsa:Address>
<wsa:ReferenceParameters>
<axis2:ServiceGroupId xmlns:axis2="http://ws.apache.org/namespaces/axis2">urn:uuid:99A029EBBC70DBEB221347349722532</axis2:ServiceGroupId>
</wsa:ReferenceParameters>
</wsa:ReplyTo>
<wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:99A029EBBC70DBEB221347349722564</wsa:MessageID>
<wsa:Action>Perform some action</wsa:Action>
<wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:63AD67826AA44DAE8C1347349721356</wsa:RelatesTo>
</soapenv:Header>
```

I would like to know how I could extract the Session GroupId from the above XML using Xpath.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You haven't specified a technology, so assuming that you haven't set up the equivalent of a .NET NameSpace manager or similar, you can use namespace agnostic Xpath as follows:

```
/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Header']
      /*[local-name()='ReplyTo']/*[local-name()='ReferenceParameters']
      /*[local-name()='ServiceGroupId']/text()
```

**Edit** Updated for Java

Without namespace aliases

```
XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expression = xpath.compile("/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Header']/*[local-name()='ReplyTo']/*[local-name()='ReferenceParameters']/*[local-name()='ServiceGroupId']/text()");
System.out.println(expression.evaluate(myXml));
```

With [NamespaceContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914013/namespacecontext-and-using-namespaces-with-xpath)

```
NamespaceContext context = new NamespaceContextMap(
    "soapenv", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", 
    "wsa", "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing",
    "axis2", "http://ws.apache.org/namespaces/axis2");
XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
xpath.setNamespaceContext(context);
XPathExpression expression = xpath.compile("/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Header/wsa:ReplyTo/wsa:ReferenceParameters/axis2:Serv‌​iceGroupId/text()");
System.out.println(expression.evaluate(myXml));
```

`local-name()` gives the tag name of the element agnostic of its namespace.
Also,  the `encoding` in your above xml document doesn't look right.

**Edit**

Assuming that `urn:uuid:` is a constant, the following XPath will strip off the first 9 characters of the result (use with either of the above XPath). If `urn:uuid` isn't constant, then you'll need to tokenize / split etc, [which is beyond my skills](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136500/does-xslt-have-a-split-function).

```
substring(string(/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Header']
                 /*[local-name()='ReplyTo']/*[local-name()='ReferenceParameters']
                 /*[local-name()='ServiceGroupId']/text()), 10)
```

Comment: @Kishorepandey The above should work with any parser - I meant that if you DID set up a Namespace manager, then you would be able to alias the namespaces and then access the element in a more 'friendly' manner, i.e. `/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Header/wsa:ReplyTo/wsa:ReferenceParameters/axis2:ServiceGroupId/text()`

Comment: @nonnb Can you please give me an example that would read my xml file and would perform the xpath expression and display the result? As I tried the expression you posted above and it seems to not be working. I would be glad if you could help me in this!

Comment: @nonnb Hi  mate, I tried running your code and it works awesome. But the problem is I get the parsing output as urn:uuid:99A029EBBC70DBEB221347349722532 and i just want the phase after uuid: and I don't need urn:uuid: What can I do to resolve it?

Comment: @Kishorepandey Updated with a substring to scrape off the prefix, assuming that it is constant.

Comment: @nonnb How would i include this in the without namespace example of yours above in the xpath.compile()? and yes it is a constant.

Comment: @Kishorepandey - just replace the string in `xpath.compile("***paste here***")`