# Java XPath only works after adding unneccessary jar

Tags: java, xpath

I'm trying to extract data from a `XML file via XPath`. My code works on a `XML` without namespaces, but as mine has a namespace I added the necessary `NamespaceContext` to the X Path object. Unfortunately the `XPath` didn't deliver any data, so after some fiddling around I ended up with my code unchanged but this jar  `xmlparserv2.jar`  added to the class-path. And voila, all of a sudden everything works perfectly.

I can see that the jar contains classes which are already in the `JDK`(1.7.0_15) but probably a different version.

So my questions are

a) Is there a way to find out what's going wrong with the original classes from the `JDK` besides from me having to debug through endless `classes`?

b) Has anybody an idea for an alternative solution/how I could change my code so that I don't have to ship an additional "unnecessary" `jar`?

Thanks
Simon

That's the code in question:

```
public class JavaApplication1 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SAXException {
    Document doc = createDoc("Persons.xml");
    parseSFMessage(doc);
}

private static void parseSFMessage(Node node) {
    if (node.getNodeName().startsWith("Persons:person") && node.hasChildNodes()) {
        print("PLZ: " + getNodeValue(node, "ns1:PLZ"));
    }
    NodeList nodeList = node.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node currentNode = nodeList.item(i);
        if (currentNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            parseSFMessage(currentNode);
        }
    }
}

private static Document createDoc(String s) {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = null;
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = builder.parse(new FileInputStream(s));
    } catch (SAXException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
    }
    return doc;
}

private static String getNodeValue(Node dom, String element) {
    NamespaceContext ctx = new NamespaceContext() {
        public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
            String uri;
            if (prefix.equals("ns1")) {
                uri = "http://someurl.com/schemas/class/Utils";
            } else {
                uri = null;
            }
            return uri;
        }
        public Iterator getPrefixes(String val) {
            return null;
        }
        public String getPrefix(String uri) {
            return null;
        }
    };
    String result = null;
    XPathFactory xpf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xp = xpf.newXPath();
    xp.setNamespaceContext(ctx);
    try {
        result = xp.evaluate(element, dom);
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}

private static void print(Object o) {
    if (o != null) {
        System.out.println(o.toString());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This might be helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914013/namespacecontext-and-using-namespaces-with-xpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to note that `DocumentBuilderFactory` is *not* namespace aware by default. You must call `factory.setNamespaceAware(true);` before you do `factory.newDocumentBuilder()` in order to get a builder that will parse the XML properly with namespace support.

As for why it worked with `xmlparserv2` I can only speculate that maybe that particular parser goes against the JAXP spec and enables namespaces by default.