# Unable to evaluate expression in XPath

Tags: java, xml, exception, xpath, transformer-model

I;m using XPath to parse XML document returned by a URL, when i run my code with given inputs it works but when giving it inputs as a user input it throws an exception.
**The Code:**

```
    class{
        private String generalQuery =  "//@*";
    method(){
        System.out.println("Enter URL");
        url = scan.nextLine();
        URL oracle = new URL(url);
        InputStream is = oracle.openStream();

        org.w3c.dom.Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory;
        DocumentBuilder builder;

        try {
            domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = builder.parse(is);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("unable to load XML: " + ex);
        }

    Map <String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String> ();

            XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
            xpath.setNamespaceContext(new NameSpaces(doc));
            XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(generalQuery);
            Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET); // exception thrown here

            NodeList nl = (NodeList) result;

            for (int i = 0 ; i < nl.getLength() ; i++){
                Node n = (Node)nl.item(i);
                params.put(n.getNodeName(), n.getNodeValue());
            }

            return params;
}
}
```

**The Exception:**

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Unable to evaluate expression using this context
```

**The class NameSpaces :**

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

public class NameSpaces implements NamespaceContext {
    private Document sourceDocument;

    public NameSpaces(Document document) {
        sourceDocument = document;
    }

    @Override
    public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
        if (prefix.equals(XMLConstants.DEFAULT_NS_PREFIX)) {
            return sourceDocument.lookupNamespaceURI(null);
        } else {
            return sourceDocument.lookupNamespaceURI(prefix);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) {
        return sourceDocument.lookupPrefix(namespaceURI);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<String> getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `doc` in this code snippet?

Comment: it's XML document created by dom

Comment: What is `NameSpaces`? The `setNamespaceContext` method expects an argument of type `NamespaceContext`. As @Ian pointed out, you also didn't tell us the type of `doc`. As written, your question won't even compile and you've left us to guess at things you should have included.

Comment: i edited the question with all information you may need

Answer (score 10):

The exception "Unable to evaluate expression using this context" may also result from a `null` document when trying to evaluate an XPath expression. (I had the same error and it took me a while to figure out I did not initialize my document properly).

In your code you have

```
try {
  // load document
}
catch (Exception ex) {
  System.err.println("unable to load XML: " + ex);
}

// happily continue
```

This is a call for trouble. If an exception happens during initialization you should STOP right there and you should not continue. If you have absolutely no idea how to handle the error, use `catch(Exception e) { throw new Error(e); }`. This will cause exceptions to bubble up and hopefully be handled by the default exception handler which prints a stack trace and exits.

As the reader of your question I don't even know where the exception was thrown. You should provide this information. Note that you can also use `someException.printStackTrace();` to get the stack trace which points you to the correct line.

Comment: Yep in my case the error was due to a null document. This was the result of an upstream bug. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be missing is a `NameSpaceContext` that you can implement yourself.

Also see this thread: [NamespaceContext and using namespaces with XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914013/namespacecontext-and-using-namespaces-with-xpath)

Example:

```
class NamespaceResolver implements NamespaceContext {

    private final Document document;

    public NamespaceResolver(Document document) {
        this.document = document;
    }

    public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
        if (prefix.equals(XMLConstants.DEFAULT_NS_PREFIX)) {
            return document.lookupNamespaceURI(null);
        } else {
            return document.lookupNamespaceURI(prefix);
        }
    }

    public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) {
        return document.lookupPrefix(namespaceURI);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public Iterator getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) {
        // not implemented
        return null;
    }

}
```

Then you initiate the XPath instance like this:

```
    getXPath().setNamespaceContext(new NamespaceResolver(doc));
```

Comment: This is *probably* right, but the OP didn't really include enough information to know for sure.

Comment: i had already made that, the something is the name of the class NameSpaceResolver is just NameSpaces in my code

Comment: @Brass Block: Maybe you also could show us the XML.
Does the xml have proper namespace declarations?

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was not due to a `null` document, but due to an *empty* document with no root element. Appending the latter solved the issue.