# Can't get value with XPath in Soap XML

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the XML and I want to find the path to **price** tag and **code**

```
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
     <getProductDetailsResponse xmlns="http://warehouse.example.com/ws">
       <getProductDetailsResult>
         <productID>12345</productID>
         <productName>Стакан граненый</productName>
         <description>Стакан граненый. 250 мл.</description>
         <price>9.95</price>
         <currency>
             <code>840</code>
             <alpha3>USD</alpha3>
             <sign>$</sign>
             <name>US dollar</name>
             <accuracy>2</accuracy>
         </currency>
         <inStock>true</inStock>
       </getProductDetailsResult>
     </getProductDetailsResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I can get the path to values if I delete namespace-*xmlns="http://warehouse.example.com/ws"*... 
The path is - /soap:Envelope/soap:Body/getProductDetailsResponse/getProductDetailsResult/price/text()

But server return it only with namespaces.

How I can get values?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Sadly, this another example of why SOAP is overkill.  You'll need to add a namespace in your XPATH query.  The way to do this differs based on how you're running your XPath (php, C#, java, xsl).  What are you using to parse your SOAP XML?

Comment: @WilliamWalseth  I try to add namespace to XPath, but it doesn't work. I parse xml in PL/SQL (Oracle)

Comment: Something like this article explains how.  After you read it you'll appreciate why SOAP is overkill.  https://community.oracle.com/thread/2553686?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: If you can apply an XSL transformation in PL/SQL run the transformation in this article, and then you can use regular XPath, without namespaces. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268182/how-to-remove-namespaces-from-xml-using-xslt

Comment: @WilliamWalseth Thanks William, for yuor suggestions. I also answer to this question by myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get all values from the XML.

For example, if you want to get the `<price>` tag value use

```
/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/*/*/*[4]/text()
```

Or code tag - use

```
/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/*/*/*/*[1]/text()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use java, you must manage prefix:

```
String expression="your path here !"

XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
NamespaceContext ctx = new NamespaceContext() {
    public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
        if (prefix == null) throw new NullPointerException("Null prefix");
        return XMLConstants.XML_NS_URI; //   .NULL_NS_URI;
    }
    public String getPrefix(String uri) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
    public Iterator getPrefixes(String uri) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
};
xpath.setNamespaceContext(ctx);
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(expression) ;
```

with

```
expression="/Envelope/Body/getProductDetailsResponse/getProductDetailsResult/price";
```

and

```
expression="/Envelope/Body/getProductDetailsResponse/getProductDetailsResult/currency/code";
```

it works, with that:

```
NodeList nodes  = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);

  for (int k = 0; k < nodes.getLength(); k ++) {
      Node nodeSegment = nodes.item(k);
      if (nodeSegment.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
          Element eElement = (Element) nodeSegment;
          System.out.println("TAG="+eElement.getTagName());              
          System.out.println("TEXT CONTENT="+eElement.getTextContent());
      }
```

you can get other solutions about prefix: [NamespaceContext and using namespaces with XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914013/namespacecontext-and-using-namespaces-with-xpath)